# Why the dataframe is altered using isin?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't understand what is happening. It was working fine, and suddently, it's not.
I got a dataframe looking like this:

[image]

And when I try to filter the indicators, the data is altered to things looking like this:

[image]

This is the code I use to filter the indicators and I expect to keep the same data

```
dfCountry = data.copy()
goodIndicators = ['GDP per capita (current US$)', 'Internet users (per 100 people)', 'other indicators']
dfCountry = dfCountry[dfCountry["Indicator Name"].isin(goodIndicators)]
```

Comment: Please show the dataframe that you got and the dataframe you expect to get

Comment: I edited my post. Is it more clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that Pandas does with large or small numbers. It uses scientific notation. You could fix it by simply round your numbers. You could even add a number between the parentheses of the `round` method to round to a specific number of decimals.

```
n_decimals = 0
df = df.round(n_decimals)  # or df = df.round() since zero is default
```

You could also change the Pandas configuration. Change the number of decimals yourself that Pandas should show.

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.5f' % x)
```

You could also just convert the float numbers to integers when you don't care about decimals.

```
for column in [c for c in df.columns if df.startswith('2')]:
    df.loc[:, column] = df.loc[:, column].apply(int)
```

More about this [Pandas notation](https://re-thought.com/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-in-pandas/).